# How to force Navigation Architecture Component to have functionality like add() method on FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to build swipe left to dismiss `Fragment`, I am using the Android Architecture Component - 'Navigation' I attained this functionality but just the thing that during that swipe transition I can not see the previous fragment behind the current one. This I can only accomplish if I have the fragments laying upon previous fragments i.e. by having functionality similar to `add()` method we use during fragment transaction If we do manually.

Comment: There is a request for this (I don't have the issue link handy), though IIRC Google rejected it. I agree that this would be a useful option for Navigation.